# After taking Picture, how to select Ok in appium when tick mark cant be located?

Tags: android-layout, selenium-webdriver, android-camera, appium

After taking Picture, how to select Ok in appium when tick mark cant be located?
only camara layout is Higlighted and i am not able to loacte tick mark or revert.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acheived this using TouchAction.

TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(new PointOption().withCoordinates(111, 222)).perform()

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code snippet. If you are able to click using android keyboard then below code should work.

```
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.SEARCH));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when i use this code i am getting  error, "The constructor KeyEvent(AndroidKey) is undefined
"

Comment: Try with adb shell "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER" if it works then use ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER)); before this make sure about you are using  capability "capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);" and correct import "import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;". If it will not works then you have to ask your Dev team to add a lister called "OnKeyListener" to make it work.

Comment: These things are not working. driver.press_keycode(66) was working for me but no idea it stoped working from few days. Any alternative to click on the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

> > ***solution for accepting image using camera app in appium.***
> >
> > keyEvent=>27, is use to capture the image using camera app.

*i used below code to accept the captured image. (but its not working)*

> > i used keyEvent=> 66, Enter button to accept the image (but its not working).
> >
> > i used keyEvent=> 84, Space button to accept the image (but its not working).

***below working code.***

> > i used keyEvent=> 22 and then i used keyEvent=> 66, it will accept the image.

```
$app.press_keycode(27)  #click on camera accept button.
$app.press_keycode(22)
$app.press_keycode(66)
sleep 2

$app.press_keycode(27)  
$app.press_keycode(22)
$app.press_keycode(66)
```

Note: repeat the code for 2 twice

> > i used keyEvent=> 21 and then i used keyEvent=> 66 and i used keyEvent=> 27, it will allow u to retake the image.
> >
> > i used keyEvent=>4, it will take back u form camera app

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled Camera and Tick button initially was using Android Key Codes:

```
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.CAMERA));
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
```

In most of the devices which I researched earlier, the above snippet worked like a charm for me. However, when I started testing on Android versions 9, 10 and 11 recently, this wasn't working and the number of tabs increased to 3 or 4. To handle this in most of the devices like Samsung, OnePlus, Google Pixel, I refactored the code as:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
// Click Camera shutter button
androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.CAMERA));
try {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(androidDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Done");
// Click Done or Tick after clicking photo (Mostly visible in OnePlus, Nokia, Google Pixel devices)
androidDriver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Done").click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
flag = true;
System.out.println("NoSuchElement for DONE Button");
}
if (flag) {
try {
// Click OK after clicking photo (Mostly visible in Samsung devices)
// No need to put WebDriverWait here as we already waited for 10 secs after clicking on Camera
androidDriver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='OK']").click();
flag = false;
System.out.println("OK Button Clicked");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
flag = true;
System.out.println("NoSuchElement for OK Button");
}
                        
}
if (flag) {
// If both above methods failed, then this may work (Mostly works for Xiaomi, Nokia devices)
androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));
hardStopWait(1000);
androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));
hardStopWait(1000);
androidDriver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
System.out.println("TABS & ENTER Pressed");
}
```